# Heterogeneity in residuals

Tags: regression, linear, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

I am very new in here, but I will try my best to create a good question.
First of all I am doing some regression on Fama and French 3 factor model and an asset.
Thus I am doing a OLS regression, using R code with the LM function, and wanting to rolling 1 step forcasts.

However by doing a Breusch Pagan test I can see my residuals contains heteroskedasticity, furthermore they are not normally distributed.

Since those a true violation of the OLS assumption, I tried different ways of correction the residuals, but without any luck.

Data contains returns for an Asset, (MK-RF), SMB and HML, which all contains both negative, zero and positive values.

**LM Regression**

> data <- na.omit(read.csv("Market_Data_industries.csv",sep = ";", header = TRUE))
> data$Date_format <- as.Date(data$Date, format = "%m-%d-%y")
> data.xts <- xts(x = data[2:14], order.by = data$Date_format)
> Model <-lm(XLF ~ Mkt.RF + SMB + HML, data=data)
> plot(Model,1)

[image]

Theese are the residuals, which a pagan tests tells me are heteroskedasticity.

I tried to correct for this by using GLS, however not with much succes.

> glsModelx <- gls(XLF ~ Mkt.RF + SMB + HML, data=data, weights = varPower(), method="ML", control = control)
> plot(glsModelx)
> plot(glsModelx$fitted, glsModelx$residuals)

[image]

Furthermore I could not do a Breusch Pagan test on the GLS model

```
> bptest(glsModelx)
```

Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :
cannot coerce class ‘c("glsStruct", "modelStruct")’ to a data.frame

Any help or suggesting is aprreciated greatly, this problem have taken me hours....

Thank you very much.

Please say if you need any other information.

Comment: Although a formal test might reject a null hypothesis of homoscedasticity, it does so only by virtue of the large amount of data.  The plot shows little indication of heteroscedasticity and no indication of an amount of heteroscedasticity that might affect the model.  The apparently non-Normal distribution is unlikely to be a problem, either.

Comment: Hi Whuber, thanks for the fast reply!
Do any case you have any sources on the fact it rejects by cirtue of the large amount of data? In this dataset there are around 5541 data points.

Answer (score 0):

The graph is unclear, because the centre is solid black. One way of dealing with this is to use solid marks (not hollow circles) but with a low alpha.

Having said that, what I think I am seeing is that for larger predictions the residual is larger. Is that the issue?

If so, then you are right that an assumption of linearity is not the best way to go. Can you devise a linearization? e.g predict $log (x+0.15)$ ?

But there is another thing to look at here: while it is true the errors are biased, they are fairly rare. For the actual business purpose, how much do they matter?

Comment: If you are concerned about hetero you might just use White standard errors. Normality is not a major issue if you have a hundred or more cases.it is better to interpret the graph rather than use formal test in any case. With a lot of data, and thus high power, you may reject the null and it may not mean anything substantively.

Comment: Hey @Chrishmorris, thanks for taking your time.

The plots, are just the regression residuals against the fitted values of the regression. My formal Breusch Pagan tests, indicates heteroskedasticity, I tried to get rid of this by implementing a GLS model, however not with much succeed. 

The businees purpose is to make a rolling regression of all the data, and use it to make 1 step forecasts. The above graphs are just a way of checking how all the data is related, and if the OLS assumptions hold.

Comment: Hey @user54285, I am concerned. However do you know how to just implement White standard errors? I had a hard time finding any litterature on it or how to implement it into r. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I know how to do it in SAS, but not R. What software are you using. Here is one discussion of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity-consistent_standard_errors

Comment: Another concern you should have if you are making predictions in the future, outside the range of your data that has its own issue. This is essentially time series and that is pretty complex. You should look at the types of issues that time series raises.